# How can we add hover effects by hovering something else, like given below? (HTML, CSS3)

Tags: html, css

I made two divs and what I want, is to use pure CSS and add something like when I hover the first div the other div change its background.
Here is my code!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Hover Effects</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #boxOne{
      background:grey;
      height:100px;
      width:100px;
      float:left;
    }
    #boxTwo{
      background:cyan;
      height:100px;
      width:100px;
      float:right;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="boxOne"></div>
  <div id="boxTwo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming they are adjacent siblings, you could use the [adjacent sibling combinator, `+`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators):

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/J5c4z/)

```
#boxOne:hover + #boxTwo {
    background:red;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the [general sibling combinator, `~`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators). Both of which assume the elements are succeeding siblings, previous siblings won't be selected.

```
#boxOne:hover ~ #boxTwo {
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: How can we add a little transition in it. I mean letting it change it's css slowly and beautifully!

Comment: What does `all` mean here?

Comment: @Faiz It will transition all properties. Here is [relevant documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)